# Moodle: since Update to 2.9.1, User can't change their password

Tags: moodle

recently I updated a moodle site from 2.6.7 to 2.9.1. 
The moodle itself runs quit fine, but user can't change their passwords anymore. 
I checked the roles settings: `("moodle/user:changeownpassword = Allow")` its like it should be.

Where can I check else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that the old theme hide the new profile window. 
My workaround is to create a simple link, to /login/change_userpassword.php inside menu.

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Preferences

Now you have a specific page to change password
access: yourmoodle/user/preferences.php
[chmagepassword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA2xW.png)

User account
Links here allow users to edit their profile information and change their password, specify how they wish to receive forum and other notifications, choose a text editor (if allowed) and view/reset their RSS token.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a local plugin called "local_resetpasswordmoodleversion...zip" install it. Make sure you enabled the plugin in its settings. After all when you go to user preferences you will find the change password activities as shown in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzVJX.png)

Comment: Please take a look at the help section, where how to post a good answer is described. I'm not downvoting nor flagging as low quality because I think it provides a solution for the question, but please try to be more detailed and try to use text formatting to improve readability.